# Adding a new column with mutate and group by

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, tidyr

I want to create a new column called age based on a previous column and group by functions. The dataset is as follows:

```
tid<- c(1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
active<- c(0,1,0,4, 0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0)
person<- c('John', 'John','John', 'John', 'Emma', 'Emma','Emma','Emma', 'Edward', 'Edward', 'Edward', 'Edward')
df<- data.frame(tid, active, person)
```

I want to create age which starts with 0 when the person is first active i.e., the value of active becomes greater than 0 for first time and then incrementally gets added with one value for the next record. Any suggestions?

I am expecting the output as follows:

```
 name     age 
 John     0
 John     0
 John     1
 John     2
 Emma     0
 Emma     0
 Emma     0
 Emma     0
 Edward   0
 Edward   0
 Edward   0
 Edward   1
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please give us an example of some strategies / code you have attempted

Comment: Shouldn't John be 0,0,1,1?

Comment: no it is supposed to be 0,0,1,2 as the age of him will be incremented to the next value in the later period i.e. in tid 1 he is 0 , 2 he is still 0, as he became active and in 3 he gets 1 and 4 he gets 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this solve it for you?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  arrange(person, tid) %>%
  mutate(active_dummy = if_else(lag(cumsum(active)) > 0, 1, 0, 0),
         age = cumsum(active_dummy)) %>% 
  select(person, age)
```

which gives you

```
# A tibble: 12 x 2
# Groups:   person [3]
   person   age
   <chr>  <dbl>
 1 John      0.
 2 John      0.
 3 John      1.
 4 John      2.
 5 Emma      0.
 6 Emma      0.
 7 Emma      0.
 8 Emma      0.
 9 Edward    0.
10 Edward    0.
11 Edward    0.
12 Edward    1.
```

Comment: why do you have the >0,1,0,0 there? it is not generic enough, it should be 0 when the active sum =1 and  then increments

Comment: thanks, it worked, you need to add arrange(tid) to make it more generic enough

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution that also does the job:

```
library(tidyverse)

age_counter = df %>% 
    arrange(tid) %>%
    group_by(person) %>% 
    filter(cumsum(active) > 0) %>% 
    mutate(age = row_number() - 1)

df %>% 
    left_join(age_counter) %>%
    replace_na(list(age = 0)) %>%
    select(person, age)
```